# Should i learn Vuejs / Angular / React because i'm use Laravel right now?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, reactjs, vue.js

I have been 2 months with Laravel. So i considering to learn JavaScript Frawework to increase my skills. I found Laravel shipped with Vuejs, but there are Angular & Reactjs with more popularity & jobs.

So what i will choose with my Laravel: Vuejs or Angular or Reactjs ?

Comment: If you're looking for a job - probably Angular or React. If you're looking for a framework for major application - probably React or Angular. If you're looking for a quickstart into SPAs - probably Vue js. If you're not familiar with frontend frameworks I think Vue is a great start.

Comment: Start from anyone, and set a goal: grasping all of vuejs/angular2/reactjs! I suggest starting from vuejs!

Comment: @devk I'm looking for a javascript framework that gave me a job and also suitable for laravel. These tough decision, because I'm going to invest a lot of time may 2+ months to learn vue / angular / react and I do not want wrong choice. I do not want to learn all of the framework. Maybe i will choose Vuejs because it's already comes with Laravel.

Comment: This is opinion based question, and It's not suitable for Stackoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no: "good answer". This question is an opinion and many people will say another framework based on their experience. It also depends what you want to achieve with your application.

The only thing that I can say is that Laravel has VueJS installed in a clean project and that Laracast provides VueJS tutorials as well. Maybe you can take a look their.

And as devsk suggest: React and Angular are more popular choices you might want to learn those if you want a job as a developer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment sir, i will choose VueJS, because im with Laravel for long time so it will be good.